# Rank is out of range after calling MPI_SCATTERV

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm using MPI to scatter a 2D array unevenly. I'm printing rank before and after calling MPI_SCATTERV function. The function works fine but when I print the rank of the process running the code after the function, it's out of bounds and has been turned into trash. I have no clue what the reason is. any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define d 8
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   
    int rank, size,i,j,sum = 0,t = 0
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
    float test[d][d];

    for(i = 0; i< d; i++)
    {
        for( j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {
            test[i][j] = rand()/ 1000;
        }
    }

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);  
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); 

    int *displace = malloc(sizeof(int)* size + 4096); 
    int *scout = malloc(sizeof(int)* size +4096);    
    int elements_per_proc = (d * d) / size;  // how many elements each rank gets
    float array[scout[rank]]; // recieve buffer for each rank
    int r = (d * d) % size;   // remainder which shows some threads
  

    for( i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        scout[i] = elements_per_proc;           
        if (r > 0) {
            scout[i]++;
            --r;
        }
        displace[i] = sum;
        sum += scout[i];                        
    }

       
    printf("rank before scatter: %d\n",rank );  // rank printed here is correct

    MPI_Scatterv(
    &test[0][0],
    scout,
    displace,
    MPI_FLOAT,
    &array,
    scout[rank] , //some ranks would recieve one more element depends on the rank
    MPI_FLOAT,
    0,
    MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("rank after scatter%d \n",rank); // rank printed here would be out of range

    MPI_Finalize();
  
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: you declare `float array[scout[rank]]` **before** you initialize `scount[rank]`

Comment: OMG, I just saw that, it worked, thanks